# 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am getting this error when I am trying to view my report on another form.

Can you help me for that error? Other point is the form is works fine on my computer.

Here is the error

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' tür başlatıcısı özel durum döndürdü. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' tür başlatıcısı özel durum döndürdü. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' dosyasını veya derlemesini ya da bağımlılıklarından birini yükleyemedi. Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor.
   konum: CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils..cctor()
   --- İç özel durum yığını izlemesinin sonu ---
   konum: CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.GetEffectiveCulture()
   konum: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.CREngineRes.GetString(String name)
   konum: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime()
   konum: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()
   --- İç özel durum yığını izlemesinin sonu ---
   konum: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
   konum: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass..ctor()
   konum: WindowsFormsApplication1.irsaliye..ctor()
   konum: WindowsFormsApplication1.irsaliyeyazdir.InitializeComponent()
   konum: WindowsFormsApplication1.irsaliyeyazdir..ctor()
   konum: WindowsFormsApplication1.Satis.linkLabel1_LinkClicked(Object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Yüklü Derlemeler **************
mscorlib
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18449 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
BK Stok Takip v1.0
    Derleme Sürümü: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/BK%20Incorporated/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34250 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18022 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34239 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18046 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18058 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34230 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs
    Derleme Sürümü: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 11.0.50727.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/BK%20Incorporated/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0/Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.resources
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18010 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Derleme Sürümü: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
    Derleme Sürümü: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 13.0.5.891
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/BK%20Incorporated/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0/CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Shared
    Derleme Sürümü: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 13.0.5.891
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/BK%20Incorporated/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0/CrystalDecisions.Shared.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
    Derleme Sürümü: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 13.0.5.891
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/BK%20Incorporated/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.DLL
----------------------------------------
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer
    Derleme Sürümü: 13.0.2000.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 13.0.5.891
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/BK%20Incorporated/BK%20Stok%20Takip%20v1.0/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.34248 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Derleme Sürümü: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Sürümü: 4.0.30319.18010 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_tr_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Hata Ayıklama **************
JIT hata ayıklamayı etkinleştirmek için, bu uygulamanın veya
bilgisayarın (machine.config) .config dosyasında
system.windows.forms bölümünde jitDebugging değeri ayarlanmış olmalıdır.
Ayrıca uygulama hata ayıklama etkin durumdayken derlenmiş
olmalıdır.

Example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

Also, my computer and the target computer is the same computer. But it's not work on target computer even its the same computer.

Comment: The error is not clearly understand as it is other than english language.  are you able to preview the crystal rerport. and what is the meaning of my computer and target computer? both are your pc?

Comment: yes both are my computer. One of the computer where i am developing the program other computer is where i am testing. And yes i can preview the CR on developing computer. but not the other

Comment: So in testing pc, are you install crystal report setup or crystal report runtime setup. The error shows, dll refernce related eigher mismatch version or not have installed properly.  You need to install crystal report runtime to give environment same as development time.

Comment: No i did not. Should i install it?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Install the Crystal Reports runtime from SAP on the server you're deploying to.

For posterity I thought I would share, it's very likely that you don't/didn't have the correct Crystal Reports runtime installed on the client or server you're running on.  I'm guessing you do/did have it installed on your dev box which is why it worked locally and not on the server.  At least in older versions of Crystal there's no way I know of to reference and deploy the DLL's with your project.

The key part of that exception is:

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime()